# How to calculate which second of song will be playing after x minutes of repeating?

Tags: algorithm

I am not doing pretty well with algorithms, so I need your help :)

Case: I play a song that lasts 3 minutes 40 seconds at 1st August 00:00 (for example). How could I be able to calculate which second of the song will be playing after (again, for expample) 3 days, 7 hours, 3 minutes and 54 seconds or any other time interval?

Sorry if it sounds lame :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a use case for the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), that gives the remainder of a division.

10 / 3 is 3 * 3 + 1. The +1 is the remainder

It's as simple as :

```
SecondOfTheSongCurrentlyPlaying = TotalSecondsElapsed % LengthOfTheSongInSeconds
```

In example, if the song lasts 3 minutes 40 seconds, this is 220 seconds.

3 days, 7 hours, 3 minutes and 54 seconds are 284 634 seconds.

```
284634 % 220 == 174 seconds
```